# Can't understand deadlock between queries on two different tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, deadlock

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    id                    bigserial   NOT NULL,

    accounts_id           int8        NOT NULL REFERENCES users.accounts (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    entities_id           int8        NOT NULL REFERENCES entities.entities (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    webhooks_id           int8        NOT NULL REFERENCES settings.webhooks (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (accounts_id, entities_id, webhooks_id, entity_revision)
);


CREATE TABLE B
(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    accounts_id BIGINT REFERENCES users.accounts(id) NOT NULL,
    clients_id BIGINT REFERENCES users.clients(id) NOT NULL,

    UNIQUE (accounts_id, clients_id, uuid)
);
```

Both the tables have other columns as well.

Now I have the following loop executing in a single transaction in my code:

```
for {
    "INSERT INTO A (
            accounts_id,
            entities_id,
            webhooks_id,
            metadata,
            state,
            available_after_time,
            retry_count,
            max_retries
        )
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) 
        ON CONFLICT (accounts_id, entities_id, webhooks_id) DO UPDATE
        SET
            metadata = $4,
            state = $5,
            available_after_time = $6,
            retry_count = $7,
            max_retries = $8,
            created_at = $9`"
   
    "UPDATE B
        SET 
            index_required = NULL,
            index_current = NULL
        WHERE
            id = $1 AND accounts_id = $2"
}
```

**Each iteration executes an insert and an update. After several iterations, the transaction commits.**

Now in my production environment, where there can be concurrent requests, I am getting deadlock errors.

And the deadlock occurs because the above `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries are waiting on each other. But I am not able to understand how they wait on each other even in concurrent settings as they are on different tables.

Any help or link to proper documentation which explains this type of scenario will really help.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to anonymize the names of two of the tables (the key ones), while leaving all the referenced table names visible.

Comment: Deadlocks cannot exist between two tables, or two statements.  They are always between two (or more) transactions.  Transactions may involve multiple statements, and multiple tables..  For each transaction, only the last statement executing will be logged, which might not be the one which caused the lock to be taken.  Also, the error message includes the type of lock being waited on, which might be important info for us to know.

Answer (score 0):

Any `INSERT` on table A and any `UPDATE` on A that modifies the foreign key will place a `FOR KEY SHARE` lock on the referenced row in B (and in C). Such a lock will conflict with any `DELETE` on B and with any `UPDATE` that modifies a primary or unique key.

Based on that, you should be able to determine which of your statements can lock with which other statements.

In the present case, the first statement can never lock with the second statement, because the `UPDATE` on B does not modify a primary or unique key. What causes the deadlock is probably that you are running several of these statements in a loop. Two transactions running the first statement can conflict with each other if they try to update the same row in A, and two transactions running the second statement can conflict if they update the same row in B.

There are two ways to avoid such deadlocks:

- Make the transactions smaller. For example, if you have the loop *outside* the transaction, so that you commit after each pair of statements, you should never get a deadlock.
- Make sure that the transactions lock the rows in the same order. For example, you could make sure that you loop through table A and B in ascending primary key order. That will also avoid deadlocks.

Comment: But in the second statement, I am not updating the primary or unique key. It's just in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Well, you are not showing the whole statement, so I cannot point to the problem. The PostgreSQL log file will show details about the deadlock. All I can provide is what locks are taken by your operations.

Comment: I have updated my question with both queries. Please have a look.

Comment: Also, I have checked PostgreSQL logs and the deadlock is between these two queries.

Comment: Good to know. Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statements as well, so that I can see the constraints. Also, even though the deadlock is between those two statements, other, earlier statements in the same transaction can also take locks that contribute to the deadlock. Are you sure that the transaction contains only these two DML statements?

Comment: Sure, I'm adding the table definition. Regarding DML statements, these two statements are in a `for` loop in the same transaction.

Comment: I have now added the the tables. Please note that I have removed the non-foreign key fields as they are not required I believe. But it has constraints info. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks for helping out. +1 for that.

Comment: `the first statement can never lock with the second statement` But as per the logs that is the case. That's why I am so confused.

Comment: The two statements in the log need not lock with each other, and I say they cannot in this case. It could have happened like this: the first statement from session 1 locks with a first statement from session 2. Session 2 is not blocked yet and continues to execute. Later, it executes the second statement, which locks with some second statement executed by session 1 earlier. Voila, a deadlock like you observe.